# how to freeze any column of nattable without using any layers other than selection layer

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I have added `DragDetectListener` and run `doCommand` in that. It gives true result but column doesn't gets freeze.
my code is :

```
natTable.addDragDetectListener(new DragDetectListener() {
    @Override
    public void dragDetected(DragDetectEvent paramDragDetectEvent) {
        boolean b = natTable.doCommand(new FreezeColumnCommand(glazedListsGridLayer.getcompositeFreezeLayer(), 0));
    }
});
```

Adding code of layer stack :

```
bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);
        GlazedListsEventLayer<IzSearchResultRowData> glazedListsEventLayer = new GlazedListsEventLayer<IzSearchResultRowData>(bodyDataLayer, eventList);
        bodyLayer = new DefaultBodyLayerStack(glazedListsEventLayer);
        ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator bodyLabelAccumulator = new ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator(bodyDataLayer);
        bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(bodyLabelAccumulator);
        // Column header layer
        selectionLayer = bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer();
        DataLayer columnHeaderDataLayer = new DefaultColumnHeaderDataLayer(bulkDataManager);
        columnHeaderDataLayer.setRowHeightByPosition(0, 35);
        final FreezeLayer freezeLayer = new FreezeLayer(selectionLayer);
        final CompositeFreezeLayer compositeFreezeLayer = new CompositeFreezeLayer(
                freezeLayer, bodyLayer.getViewportLayer(), selectionLayer);
        ColumnHeaderLayer columnHeaderLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayer(columnHeaderDataLayer, compositeFreezeLayer, selectionLayer);
```

Another Thing :
I am getting position coordinates through selection layer. when i am running freeze command as 
natTable.doCommand(new FreezeColumnCommand(glazedListsGridLayer.getSelectionLayer(), 0));

Its giving false result.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing your layer stack. Maybe you have a more complicated layer composition and the command is lost on the way because of the index-position-transformation. Try to execute the command on the layer for which you provide the position coordinates.

```
natTable.addDragDetectListener(new DragDetectListener() {
    @Override
    public void dragDetected(DragDetectEvent paramDragDetectEvent) {
        boolean b = glazedListsGridLayer.getcompositeFreezeLayer().doCommand(
            new FreezeColumnCommand(glazedListsGridLayer.getcompositeFreezeLayer(), 0));
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried what I suggested? Fire the command on the layer for which you specify the position coordinates? And the SelectionLayer is below the FreezeLayer, so that probably is the issue that the command is not processed if you specify the position like that.

Comment: Tried like this, its giving false :
glazedListsGridLayer.getSelectionLayer().doCommand(new FreezeColumnCommand(glazedListsGridLayer.getcompositeFreezeLayer(), 0));

Comment: where to you see the SelectionLayer in my example code? I just explained that the SelectionLayer is below the CompositeFreezeLayer, so executing the command on the SelectionLayer means that nobody is taking care of the command. The FreezeCommandHandler is registered on the CompositeFreezeLayer. So you need to at least execute the command on that one. Any layer below is not working.

Comment: Sorry i am new to nattable. Executing on compositeFreezeLayer results in true then also column is not getting freeze ?

Comment: Your composition looks strange. Why do you use the DefaultBodyLayerStack and then stack additional layers on top of the SelectionLayer? I think your layer stack is messed up. Please check our examples and the getting started tutorial to get a better idea of the NatTable concepts